# How can I update the style of block element and pass an argument to PHP funciton

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm sure I am over complicating things but I am trying to accomplish 2 things with the referenced HTML.  When user selects an option, I want to toggle the display style of the leaderTable from hidden to visible if it meets the criteria (this I have done successfully with the JS that follows)

I also want to pass the value of the selected option as an argument to a PHP function that will set a $_SESSION variable which I can use.

From my understanding I would have to use an AJAX request to  communicate the value to the php script but I don't fully understand AJAX POST vs GET.

**HTML**

```
<select id="rate_type" name="rate_type">
<option value="">Select One</option>
<option value="1">Non-Supervisors</option>
<option value="2">Supervisors</option>
<option value="3">Manager</option>
<option value="4">Director</option>
<option value="5">Sales</option>
<option value="6">Executive</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
      var eSelect = document.getElementById('rate_type');
        var leaderTable = document.getElementById('leadership');

        eSelect.onchange = function() {
            if((eSelect.selectedIndex == 2) || (eSelect.selectedIndex == 3) || (eSelect.selectedIndex == 4) || (eSelect.selectedIndex == 5) || (eSelect.selectedIndex == 6)){

                leaderTable.style.display= 'block';


                } else {

                leaderTable.style.display = 'none';

            }

        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using jquery?

Comment: an ajax request is no different than a normal HTTP request.

GET specifies parameters in the URL and is best suited for getting dynamic content within content frameworks, it shouldn't be used for other purposes.  POST is more secure, and can send more data.  You will still need to do server side validation, and if you are new to AJAX, use jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will add the jquery src from google, and make an ajax request to the server on change.  See [jQuery POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for more info.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#rate_type').change(function() {
            if(($(this).val() == 2) || ($(this).val() == 3) || ($(this).val() == 4) || ($(this).val() == 5) || ($(this).val() == 6)){
                $('#leadership').show();
            } else {
                $('#leadership').hide();
            }

            // this is the shorthand post
            $.post(
                // the url
                '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>',
                // the request parameters to send
                {
                    rate_type: $('#rate_type').val(),
                    some_other_var: 'junk'
                },
                function(data) {
                    // do something here
                    console.log(data);
            });
        });
        // fire the change event on load if needed
        $('#rate_type').change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: I was able to implement it with the code you posted.  If I may, what additional steps would I have to take to update the data on the page if the user made a mistake when selecting #rate_type and wanted to choose another.  I stored the rate type in a session variable so that I could pass it as an argument for php function to pull results from the SQL database. Can JQuery/Ajax could probably pull the data with each call of the function and not even need to use PHP at this point. Thanks very much .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, almost nobody writes "raw" JS anymore. Use a JS library that makes life easy. I recommend jQuery. It will take you a few minutes to understand it, but it can implement AJAX in [1 line](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Regarding the difference between AJAX POST and GET, it doesn't matter for you. You can do either one. In your PHP script look for the parameter using `$_REQUEST[..]` and you will cover both cases.

Last, here are some ideas:

1. If you need to communicate the value immediately to the server, you will have to use AJAX
2. If you don't mind refreshing the page when you communicate the value to the server, you can skip AJAX and do it by changing window.location in JS and including the parameter in the URL. AJAX is simple to use and avoids the refresh, so it's better..
3. If you don't need to communicate the value to the server immediately, you can save it in JS as a cookie (using `document.cookie`), and it will arrive to the server with the next request the user makes. Then just look for it in PHP using `$_COOKIE[..]`